# Can I use std::string_view with getline when parsing a file?

Tags: c++, string, c++17, string-view

I recently learned about std::string_view and how it is much faster than allocating strings so I am trying to use this in place of std::string where possible.

Is there a way of optimizing a loop that parses a file line by line to use std::string_view instead?

This is the code I am working on.

```
    std::string line;

    // loop until we find the cabbage tag
    while (std::getline(csd, line))
    {
        //DO STUFF
        if (line.find("</STOP>") != std::string::npos)
            break;
    }
```

Comment: You still need an `std::string` to _own_ the data (getline just reads characters from a stream and needs to put them somewhere). But you can create a view simply with `std::string_view lineView = line;` and go from there for parsing.

Comment: For `getline` you need `std::string` anyway, then you might use `string_view` for `find` but it doesn't make sense to me - it will not speed up anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is `mmap`, that allows you to read into a file's data without copying them. Reading from a stream in C++ will always copy the data. You can then, of course, use `std::string_view` to point at the data revealed by `mmap`, and do all operations you like.

Comment: `mmap` is for posix system, in windows there's `CreateFileMapping`

Answer (score 1):

No. A `string_view` is:

- A constant view into some storage, so you can't read into the `string_view`
- Does not own the storage, but instead "refers" to some other storage, so there's nowhere for `getline` to put the information that it reads.

However, once you read the data into a `string`, you can make a `string_view` and pass that to a routine for parsing (avoiding passing a copy in that case).